# Slot not displayed while using vaadin applayout

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

I'm trying to build application using vaadin's [vaadin-app-layout-flow](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-app-layout-flow).
[here](https://github.com/bilak-poc/vaadin-applayout-slot-issue) is sample app where I want to create slot-ed parts while using [mainlayout](https://github.com/bilak-poc/vaadin-applayout-slot-issue/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/MainLayout.java) which is using `app-layout`.  I want to create some kind of master-detail view so in my [UserMasterView](https://github.com/bilak-poc/vaadin-applayout-slot-issue/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/UserMasterView.java) i'm trying to set entire component/element as `master-content` slot with this code `getElement().setAttribute("slot", "master-content");`.
When I display the view on `localhost:9999` which should use `mainlayout` the content of `UserMasterView` is not displayed. However when I navigate to `localhost:9999/users` where `mainlayout` is not used content of `UserMasterView` is displayed without problem.

So the question is...is it possible to use `slot` with `app-layout`? Or is there any other problem which I don't see?